How can VSZ be bigger than physical RAM?
In my system Firefox has 11GB Virtual Set Size (VSZ), but my computer has just 8GB of physical RAM.
How it is possible that Ubuntu can allocate more than the capacity of physical RAM? I know about VSZ, RSS, paging and their differences.

Since you say you "know about VSZ, RSS, paging and their differences", I'm curious: what do you think VSZ is?

The maximum memory that a programme can occupy

The word "can" is doing a lot of heavy lifting there. I can go to the moon, as in I am allowed to go there, but can I actually go to the moon (as in physically travel there)? Realistically not.

... @afsrgdtfhygjhjgfdse "The maximum memory that a programme can occupy"... Not really ... But rather an informative and somehow hypothetical and inaccurate indication of the amount of physical memory that process would use if it happened to load all its libraries and functions all at once into memory which rarely the case especially with user-space processes ... So merely a reference I think.

.... Another thing regarding "inaccurate" is, for example, shared libraries seem to be counted multiple time against each process and it's tree of sub-processes.

Perhaps this answer can offer a bit of insight into how memory is reported?

This question is similar to: Extremely large "VIRT" memory usage reported by `top`. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
